# ld: framework not found MBProgressHUD(Nativescript)

Tags: nativescript

I'm new in using Xcode and I want archive project. It cause this kind of error after I update to Xcode 7.3 and cocopod 1.0.0. And I try downgrade to Xcode 7.1 also same. What setting will cause this error message?

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/bae-nb-050/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SL-fbodsjqbjvdhcgeemiobyapkoekm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SL/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/MBProgressHUD'
    ld: framework not found MBProgressHUD
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have upgraded your Xcode or cocoapods to a newer version. I recommend that you do a clean and a rebuild of your project.  The same goes for when upgrading natviescript.

- `tns platform remove ios`
- `tns platform add ios`
- `tns prepare ios`